# Task<T> вернуть null, не прерывая задачу

Tags: c#, .net

Одна задача, ожидает выполнение другой задачи, как только возвращаем `null` из ожидаемой задачи, происходит прерывание выполнения другой.

Как вернуть `null` из `Task<T>`, при этом не прервать выполнение родительского `Task<T>`, и продолжить выполнение в штатном режиме?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class TaskOperation
        {
            public bool GetNUll { get; set; }
        }
        public class SomeTasks
        {

            public async Task<ObservableCollection<TaskOperation>> GetAllTasks()
            {
                ObservableCollection<TaskOperation> taskOperations = new ObservableCollection<TaskOperation>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
                {
                    taskOperations.Add(new TaskOperation { GetNUll = i % 2 == 0 });
                }

                int t = 0;

                foreach (var taskOperation in taskOperations)
                {
                    if (!(await GetTask(taskOperation)).GetNUll)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{t}");
                    }
                }

                return taskOperations;
            }
            public Task<TaskOperation> GetTask(TaskOperation operation)
            {
                return operation.GetNUll ? null : Task.Factory.StartNew(() => operation);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeTasks someTasks = new SomeTasks();
            Task.Run(async () => await someTasks.GetAllTasks());

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Данная задача будет прервана на первой же итерации цикла.

Comment: Что значит `вернуть null из Task<T>` ?

Comment: @tym32167: т.е. вместо объекта `T` вернуть null.

Comment: добавь больше объяснений и примеров кода что именно ты хочешь и зачем

Comment: То есть вы хотите вернуть результат операции не прерывая операцию? Это бессмыслица какая то.

Comment: Напишите пример кода, что у вас есть и какая в нем проблема. А то без кода непонятно что вам нужно.

Comment: пока по твоим требованиям вполне подходит: `return null`

Comment: скорее всего, вы не правильно построили логику задачи, напишите изначальное задание, а то из того, что вы написали действительно бессмыслица какая то

Comment: Добавлен минимальный воспроивзодимый пример.

Comment: Я понял, вам скорее всего надо вместо `return null` писать `return Task.FromResult((TaskOperation)null)`  в методе `GetTask`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поглядим на код:

```
async Task ParentTask()
{
    await ChildTask(); // ожидаем Task<T>, всё хорошо
    await ChildTaskNull(); // await null - ошибка
}

Task<string> ChildTask()
{
    return Task.FromResult<string>(null);
}

Task<string> ChildTaskNull()
{
    return null;
}
```

Смотрим что тут происходит:

У нас есть родительская функция и 2 дочерние. В родительской мы сначала вызываем `ChildTask()`, который возвращает экземпляр `Task<string>`, который мы можем ожидать. Потому `await ChildTask();` работает нормально.

Далее, `ChildTaskNull()` возвращает NULL, но NULL - это не экземпляр задачи, это просто пустой указатель. потому `await ChildTaskNull();` превращается в `await null`, что и порождает исключение в родительской задаче.

Как вывод, если ваша функция НЕ асинхронная и просто возвращает `Task<T>`, и вам надо вернуть null как результат операции, используйте `return Task.FromResult<T>(null)` или `Task.FromResult((T)null)`